# Exclude lines based on long list of line numbers

Tags: command-line, sed, perl, awk

I have a long list of line numbers (35389208) that I do not want in my file. By line number I mean the line in my file (e.g. line 277). My list of line numbers I do not want looks like:

```
277
278
279
280
289
290
291
292
321
322
....
```

Whats best way to exclude these line numbers from my file? Solution in perl sed or awk (or anything else).

Answer (score 2):

If reading all of the line numbers into memory is an option, you can do it like this with `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR == NR { h[$1]; next } !(FNR in h)' line-numbers.txt input.txt
```

If you have limited memory available and your `line-numbers.txt` file is numerically sorted, you can do it like this:

*delete-lines.awk*

```awk
BEGIN {  
  lines_file = "line-numbers.txt"
  if(!(getline n < lines_file)) { 
    print "Unable to open lines file " lines_file > "/dev/stderr" 
    exit 
  } 
} 

FNR != n

FNR == n {
  getline n < lines_file
}
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f delete-lines.awk input.txt
```

Testing where `line-numbers.txt` contains:

```
277
278
279
280
289
290
291
292
321
322
```

and `input.txt` is represented by `seq 325`.

First with the line-numbers in memory:

```
seq 325 | awk 'FNR == NR { h[$1]; next } !(FNR in h)' line-numbers.txt -
```

then with the line-numbers being read one at a time:

```
seq 325 | awk -f delete-lines.awk -
```

Output in both cases (lines 1 through 274 are omitted):

```
.
.
.
275
276
281
282
283
284
285
286
287
288
293
294
295
296
297
298
299
300
301
302
303
304
305
306
307
308
309
310
311
312
313
314
315
316
317
318
319
320
323
324
325
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You could try using a regex with `sed`:</strike>

```
sed '/^[0-9]*$/d' filename.txt
```

This will remove the lines which only have numbers in them from your file.

The following Perl script will remove the *n*-th line from the file `input.txt` and output the rest to `stdout`. Line numbers can be specified in `line_numbers.txt`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @lines_to_exclude;

open(my $fh_line_numbers, "<", "line_numbers.txt") or die "Failed to open file: $!\n";
while(<$fh_line_numbers>) { 
  chomp; 
  push @lines_to_exclude, $_;
} 
close $fh_line_numbers;

my $linecounter = 1;

open (my $fh_datafile, '<', 'input.txt') or die "Cannot open $filename: $!";

while ( my $line = <$fh_datafile> ) {

  if ( ! ( $linecounter ~~ @lines_to_exclude ) ) {
    print $line;
  }

  $linecounter++;
}

close($fh_datafile);
```

( the `~~` operator is only available in perl >= 5.10 )

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood. I have a list of line numbers and I want to omit those line numbers from my file. So if my file is filename.txt I want to omit lines 277,278,279...etc. Those lines don't necessarily have the numbers 277 etc. in them.

Comment: @Benjamin I indeed misunderstood, I updated my answer

Comment: I ended up doing a perl script as well. If mine doesn't do the correct thing I will give yours a try.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/.*/&d/' line-numbers-to-delete-file | sed -f - file-to-be-shortened
```

Generate a script from the file containing the lines to delete and feed it to an instance of sed using the file which you want shortened as input.

Answer (score 0):

To delete number in the begining of line

```
sed 's/^[0-9]*//g' filename.txt
```

Comment: Read my comment below

Answer (score 0):

Note that except for the additional code in attempt 2, all the code actually does the opposite of what OP asked. As you can see in attempt 2, it is easy to adapt the commands.

I had a textfile with 1.108.752 lines in it, about 83 MB in size. I wanted to get 46.744 lines from it, ranging between the 15th and the 1.108.716th line, which is about every 24th line on average.

## tl;dr;

Second attempt is faster than first. Third only works for fewer lines.

## First Attempt (bad)

For every line I want, `sed` reads lines from the start of the textfile, but not print them (`-n`). When it reaches the line I want, print it (`p`), then quit (`q`) instead of reading to the end of the file. Then do that again for the next linenumber.

Obviously, this takes a little longer each run, because `sed` has to go through more lines than before each time.

If I calculated that right, in my case that would take about 307332472188 passes through the textfile overall. Oh my.

Note that for this approach the order of lines is irrelevant in the linenumbers file:

```
while read line; do
    sed -n "${line}{p;q}" "${INFILE}"
done
```

Timing results: `2568.80s user 256.10s system 92% cpu 51:00.37 total`. No good.

## Second Attempt (better)

This reads the linenumbers from the file and appends a `p` (again, for printing this line). This string is piped to the next `sed`, which reads from a file (`-f`), which here is `STDIN` written as `-`, which each time is the output from the first `sed`, which is actually the linenumber to be printed:

```
sed 's/$/p/' "${LINENUMS}" | sed -n -f - "${INFILE}"
```

Timing results: `146.54s user 0.18s system 100% cpu 2:26.70 total`. Pretty good!

If you want to *not* print the lines from the linefile (like OP wanted to do), slightly change the command so that linenumbers are being *d*eleted instead of *p*rinted, and print all other lines instead of deleting them (-n):

```
sed 's/$/d/' "${LINENUMS}" | sed -f - "${INFILE}"
```

## Third Attempt (badder)

This wasn't working for me at all because I had too many lines I wanted to extract. It should work for (much) fewer lines though, but I don't know the limit to that.

I tried to create a long string for sed, which I expected would lead to `sed` going through the file only once (!), not printing anything except the linenumbers from the string:

```
sed -n "12p;15p;24p;345p;...;12345;" ${INFILE}"
```

but that would result in a string about `420076` characters long, which upon pumping into `sed` simply led to `sed: Argument list is too long`. Which is understandable.